# Area of a simple closed curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Let C be a simple closed curve in a region where Green's Theorem holds. Show that the area of the region is:
>
> \begin{equation}
> A=\int_{C}xdy=-\int_{C}ydx
> \end{equation}

Green's theorem for area states that for a simple closed curve, the area will be $A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{C}xdy-ydx$, so where does this equality come from?

Comment: Nop. What can be deduced from Green's Theorem is that the are is **half** that integral: $$A=\frac12\int_Cxdy-ydx$$

Comment: I edited the question, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ be the interior of the simple closed curve $\mathcal{C}$. Then we are after
$$ A = \iint_D 1\ dxdy$$
We need to find some $f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ such that $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} = 1$. Observe that $f(x,y) = (0,x)$ does the trick. Then by Green's Theorem,
\begin{align}
  A &= \iint_D 1\ dxdy\\
  &= \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\right)\ dxdy\\
  &= \int_\mathcal{C} (f_1dx + f_2dy)\\
  &= \int_\mathcal{C} x\ dy
\end{align}
And the other equality is got by defining a different $f(x,y)$ (I'll won't spoil the fun for you there).

EDIT: Let's illustrate this integral on the area of a cirlce of radius $r$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the curve parametrized by $\mathbf{r}(t) = (r\cos(t),r\sin(t)), 0 \le t < 2\pi$.

Then,
\begin{align}
  A &= \int_\mathcal{C} x dy \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} (r\cos(t))\frac{dy}{dt} dt\\
&= r^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(t)\cos(t) dt\\
&= r^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2t)) dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}r^2 \left[t + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2t) \right|_0^{2\pi}\\
&= \pi r^2
\end{align}
as expected!

Comment: Isn't that a particular case? Shouldn't the equality hold for every simple closed curve?

Comment: @IchVerloren $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary simple closed curve, so I've not assumed any particular simple closed curve here.

Comment: I see it. It seems that you switched the differentials tho. It should be $\int_{C}(f_{2}dy+f_{1}dx)$ right?. For the other equality f(x,y)=(-y,0) works!

Comment: @IchVerloren Yes you're absolutely right! I've fixed it now and added an example to show that this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Stokes' theorem on manifolds:
$$\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega$$
where $\omega$ is a k form, and $M$ is a differentiable manifold.

For a closed curve in the plane, the area form is $d\omega=dx\wedge dy$. So the area of $M$ is just the region bounded by $\partial M$ - the closed, simple curve. Therefore for any $\omega$ such that $d\omega = dx\wedge dy$ you can find the area by integrating $\omega$ on the curve $\partial M$, here are some examples:
$$Area = \int_M dx\wedge dy = \int_{\partial M}x dy = -\int_{\partial M}ydx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial M}xdy - ydx$$